# OpenCV 3.0.0 error with Visualstudio13

Tags: c++, opencv

> **Error** error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp': No such file or directory
>   **File** c:\users\nayir\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\sample\sample\sample.cpp
>   **Line** 20
>   **Column** 1
>   **Project** sample

I couldn't find any helpful solution for this error

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx6oqNfteEuOc2oyZ1ZWbjhKMEE/view?usp=sharing

I am using visual studio 2013 and opencv 3.0.0 and I am trying to excute local binary histogram method in facerecognition but it always make such errors

Comment: The error is pretty clear you need to add the paths to the files have you followed the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to)?

Comment: Reformat error for better readability, removed irrelevant tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from 3.0 on, the face recognition code has been moved to [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) please have a close look at the readme there, on how to integrate it. since both repos need to be synchronizized tightly, most probably you will have to update your main opencv repo to current 3.1.

you will also find updated [samples there](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face/samples)